# how to decrypt ecryptfs file with private key instead of passphrase

Tags: linux, encryption, ecryptfs

I have an encrypted share folder on my synology NAS DS413 (which uses ecryptfs).  I  can manually mount the encrypted folder and read the decrypted files without issue, using synologies GUI. For some reason, I have never been able to mount the encrypted folder using my passphrase . But I can always do it by using the private key generated during ecryptfs setup.

So I have since been doing some research on decrypting the encrypted files without a synology (for example if this thing catches fire or is stolen and I need to restore from backup). I've read several threads and howto's on decrypting synology/ecryptfs encrypted shares using linux and encryptfs-utils. But the howto always tells you to provide the passphrase and never mention the use of the key for decryption. So my question is how do I decrypt using the key (which works to mount and decrypt with synology's software)?  The key I have is 80 bytes and is binary.  The first 16 bytes are integers only and the remaining bytes appear to be random hex.

Thanks for any tips!

Comment: I'd be far more concerned about disk failure & power surges, or accidental overwrite, than I would be about fire & theft. And what's synologies & just wondering what system are you running, Ubuntu, Arch, Debian, etc?

Comment: raid 5 and ecryptfs backup to amazon glacier

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Short answer: Use the passphrase `$1$5YN01o9y` to reveal your actual passphrase from the keyfile with `ecryptfs-unwrap-passphrase` (the backslashes escape the `$` letters):

```
printf "%s" "\$1\$5YN01o9y" | ecryptfs-unwrap-passphrase keyfile.key -
```

Then use your passphrase with one of the instructions you probably already know, like AlexP's answer here or [Robert Castle's article](https://web.archive.org/web/20190723214141/https://robertcastle.com/2012/10/howto-recover-synology-encrypted-folders-in-linux/).

Or do it all in a single line:

```
mount -t ecryptfs -o key=passphrase,ecryptfs_cipher=aes,ecryptfs_key_bytes=32,ecryptfs_passthrough=no,ecryptfs_enable_filename_crypto=yes,passwd=$(printf "%s" "\$1\$5YN01o9y" | ecryptfs-unwrap-passphrase /path/to/keyfile.key -) /path/to/encrypted/folder /path/to/mountpoint
```

I just tested the whole decryption process with a keyfile and can confirm its working:

- Created a new encrypted shared folder in DSM 6.2 and downloaded the keyfile.
- Shut down the NAS, removed a drive, connected it to a Ubuntu x64 18.04.2 machine and mounted the raid and volume group there.
- Installed `ecryptfs-utils` and successfully got access to the decrypted data using the mount command mentioned above with the downloaded keyfile.

Credits: I found that `$1$5YN01o9y`-passphrase in [a post in a German Synology forum](https://www.synology-forum.de/showthread.html?76648-Verschl%C3%BCsselten-Ordner-automatisch-einbinden-%28Skript%29&p=633034&viewfull=1#post633034). The user that probably actually found out the secret [in 2014 is known there as Bastian (b666m)](https://www.synology-forum.de/showthread.html?48569-Script-Verschl%C3%BCsselten-Ordner-via-Keyfile-%28-key%29-entschl%C3%BCsseln&p=387288&viewfull=1#post387288).

Comment: Wow, that's excellent!  It took 4 years, but we finally have the answer :)

Answer (score 2):

See by "[How To Recover Synology encrypted folders in Linux](https://robertcastle.com/2012/10/howto-recover-synology-encrypted-folders-in-linux/)" by Robert Castle. Summary:

```
MOUNTOPTIONS=""
for option in                           \
  "key=passphrase"                      \
  "ecryptfs_cipher=aes"                 \
  "ecryptfs_key_bytes=32"               \
  "ecryptfs_passthrough=no"             \
  "ecryptfs_enable_filename_crypto=yes" \
; do
  MOUNTOPTIONS="${MOUNTOPTIONS}${MOUNTOPTIONS:+,}$option"
done
sudo mount -t ecryptfs -o $MOUNTOPTIONS,passwd=$PASSWORD $CRYPTDIR $TARGET
```

Comment: Sorry, you're using the passphrase and not the key.

Comment: @kevincw01: Read the linked article, not just my summary. You can mount the filesystem by first adding the key to the keyring.

Comment: I did read it.  In fact that's the article I originally read before I posted this question.  I reread it just now to make sure and I don't see anything that talks about how to use the key file instead of the passphrase.

Comment: @kevincw01: What exactly is "the private key generated during ecryptfs setup"? It is something else than the eCryptfs wrapped passphrase?